# Multiple AJAX calls work locally but fail on the server (500 error resource not found)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is something weird. I am developing an app that checks via AJAX if the session timed out at every page load and every user action. On top of this, I make other ajax calls for other user actions.

This works well on my xampp server, locally. However, when I'm testing them on my client's server, a shared host working on a CPanel thingy, the first AJAX call works, and then all the other calls fail with an error code of 500.

Is this familiar to someone?

Comment: Can you check the apache error_log of your client's server to check the error ?

Comment: you mean "500 Internal Server Error" ?

Comment: yes, 500 Internal Server Error. Apparently, the server recorded no errors.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a session lock, Check that your session is not locked after the first session starts. I had once face these problem in my own PHP MVC framework where i was actually requesting multiple times the url with the jquery, after first one then my session was locked, check on it, if that might be the case